# Broadband Connection Problem?

Tags: windows-vista, networking, internet

Okay I tried to connect my broadband cable to both my laptops and got the following:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection: 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a992:4a11:f9d4:6696%30 
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.121.133 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I'm using Windows Vista.

No ROUTER

Cable Broadband Internet From Modem To Laptop Is being used

Techs say its a LOOPING Problem

I also tried to connect the broadband internet to my PS3. It won't even work on that it says no IP Address was found.

Cable modem is an Ambit U10C018.

[image: alt text w00t]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say "no router" it is expected that you get IP address from the broadband provider as part of your negotiations over the modem. However, your dump shows you are using a [Link-local](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) `169.254/16` IP address. This will be picked up by Windows Vista when you **do not** get an address over DHCP (and have not configured static address).

This means, you have not been able to complete a connect with the broadband provider.

---

You might find some useful notes at this [Apple Support discussion thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=943512&tstart=141).
There are notes to connect over USB to the `Ambit U10C018` modem.
Another [older reference](http://forums.techguy.org/networking/765443-connecting-modem-through-router.html).

---

It appears that the model is now called the [`Ubee DOCSIS 2.0 modem`](http://www.ubeeinteractive.com/index.php/products/product-overview/docsis_2.0_modem/),
that link has a PDF data sheet reference and a **USB driver download** link.
There is a UserGuide link: [U10C018UserGuide.pdf](http://www.jetbroadband.com/images/stories/pdfs/U10C018userguide.pdf) and [here](http://www.charter.com/customers/GETBINARY.xbin?ID=2105).

I presume that the modem is supplied by your cable company and is compatible with their technology.

Comment: How do I correct this problem?

Comment: of course it was supplied by the cable comapny.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your modem by pressing the reset button behind the modem with a pen head. Most of them keep the first MAC address they got connected to at first boot and then lock to it. By resetting your modem, you clear the last MAC address and then you'll be able to connect it to something else. You must do this every time you change what you plug into the modem.

That's how it works for me at least if I want to plug my modem straight in something else then my router.

Also getting a cheap router could be an easy solution if you can afford it.

Hope this help.

Comment: that didn't work for me at all.

Comment: Can you tell me what the brand and the model of the modem you got? With this I might be able to help you better. thx

Comment: do NOT reset your cable modem without consulting your ISP's technical support, it may very well be preconfigured with different settings than the factory default settings!

Comment: Model# U10C018 Make I think "Ambit".

Comment: To Molly, most of the time DOCSYS modem retrieve their configuration file from the ISP server when they're plug in. That's how they control you connection speed and much more. That's how my ISP work here in Canada. So resetting the modem just force the modem to retrieve the last config from server sure it do it automaticaly too but at very spaced interval.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you have another ethernet cable to test with?  Bad cables are rare, but it's possible.
- I have to reset (power-off/power-on) my cable modem every time I switch devices, so make sure you do that.
- Also, ask the techs to explain the looping problem to you and write down what they say here.

I know you used 3 different devices, but just to be thorough, double-check DHCP on your network card settings.

> Start -> Run -> ncpa.cpl -> right-click your LAN adapter -> Properties -> Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) -> Properties

Make sure `Obtain an IP address automatically` and `Obtain DNS server address automatically` are both selected.

---

So it's this one?  What happens when you connect via USB?  Any way you can access the modem to see what's going on through that?

(^see question)

---

Here's something else to try.  According to the manual [nik linked](https://superuser.com/questions/33304/broadband-connection-problem/33315#33315), the IP of the router should be http://192.168.100.1 (pp. 25).  Statically assign an IP for your LAN adapter.

```
IP address:            192.168.2.5
Subnet mask:           255.255.0.0
Default gateway:       192.168.100.1
Preferred DNS server:  blank or 208.67.222.222 (OpenDNS)
```

Browse to http://192.168.100.1 and tell us if you get something.

Comment: I bought an extra cable just in-case the broadband was going to give me some trouble so I'm way ahead of you. As for setting the network card I did that about 8 or 9 times to many.

Comment: Yeah, that the one. Well I don't have a USB cable sad to say is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Well USB cables on modems are just an alternate way of connecting to the internet.  I thought perhaps you could use it to check inside the modem to get more info.  Is this a recent internet installation?  The cable guy isn't supposed to go home until you can access Google.

Comment: Just got it last week, been trying to find out the problem ever since.