# Raspberry Pi 3 Wifi Connecting Issues

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

So I've done this a million times and I have no idea why its failing now. Simply trying to setup the wifi for the raspberry pi 3 in the lite command line only version. I've been using the instruction on the pi website found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

I put in the info and write to the wpa_supplicant config file, and when I restart the wlan service and use the ifconfig command I see that the pi's ip address is 169.254.232.41 My gateway is 192.168.2.1 so this is way off. It says network unreachable when I try to ping anything on the network I'm trying to connect it to. I saw some weird issues with 169.254.. issues online, but they seem to be happening when the pi is connected to a computer via ethernet. Whereas mine is just the keyboard and monitor, trying to get it to connect. I have another pi, that I have put on the network and all of the modified files are the same between them.

I wondered if I had a corrupt disk image or something, so I redownloaded the latest and tried again with no avail. I wonder if there is a hardware issue, but the pi scans normally, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. After getting 5 pages deep in multiple google searches, I've decided to swallow my pride and ask for help.

Thanks!

Comment: An IP address in the 169.254.X.X range basically means your interface was unable to get an IP address so has assigned on by itself - essentially, something went wrong. Can you past the output of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file?

Comment: The standard setup I believe: auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: Do you have a functioning DHCP server on the LAN? Can that pi contact it?  If you setup the Pi a static IP to from within your LAN subnet, does it work?  Is the other Pi you have working also a v3 Pi?

Comment: This may help: http://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range/1106943#1106943. . . If it's getting it's IP via DHCP then check DHCP or applicable configs; otherwise some suggestion on that post you may find helpful

Comment: So I figured it out! The router DCHP settings were only going from .2 to .50 for some reason. I moved it to the standard .255 upper limit, and it works now! Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the router being the problem and not the pi :D

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 0):

I was really smart, and the router I was using ran out of addresses to give out because it was only addressing between .2 and .50. I moved the upper limit to .255 and everything works like a champ!