# Windows 7 WiFi - Limited access - DHCP client can't obtain IP address

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dhcp

since few days I cannot properly connect to ANY wifi (work, in public or to my home wifi). Whenever I try to connects, Windows shows a limited availability message.
Other devices are able to connect to the same router, only my laptop can't. So - that rules out router configuration issue.

After connecting to wifi and doing ipconfig /all I see following information:

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

```
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-FD-CE-E6-BF-0E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e83b:7832:46fd:4a86%29(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.74.134(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 212663758
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-B6-CB-FE-20-47-47-E9-E0-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

so, because assigned address is link-local, I understand that Windows was not able contact DHCP server that sits on my wifi router.

Both DHCP client and WLAN autoconfiguration services are enabled, but in the log I see following error:

> Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the
>   DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0xAEFDCEE6BF0E.
>   The following error occurred: 0x79. Your computer will continue to try
>   and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP)
>   server.

This error allowed me to trace that I have TWO adapters with the same MAC, one physical and one virtual:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AE-FD-CE-E6-BF-0E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AC-FD-CE-E6-BF-0E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e83b:7832:46fd:4a86%29(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.74.134(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 212663758
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-B6-CB-FE-20-47-47-E9-E0-1C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I disable the virtual one with (using commands from this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd815243%28VS.85%29.aspx and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/eventid-1001-dhcp-your-computer-was-not-assigned/2b5227e0-8171-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) - it didn't helped, still can't connect to any wifi.

Drivers were reinstalled, laptop rebooted many times. I use Virtual Box if that somehow important (it creates some additional virtual devices).

Anyone have any hints on how to proceed? What could I check more?

Comment: "so, because assigned address is link-local, I understand that Windows was not able contact DHCP server that sits on my wifi router." That's incorrect. It is the other way around, Because Windows cannot/don't contact a DHCP server, your IP address is link-local.

Comment: The Miniport Adapter is only important for sharing your wireless connection as hotspot. I don't believe this is the problem, but to disable it, go to the command prompt as admin and type this: `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` followed by `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow`. You could also disable IPv6 on the main adapter, as it's not needed for a home network.

Comment: What happens if you statically assign a valid IP address, gateway, and DNS server to your wireless network adapter then connect to the WiFi network?  Do you have Internet access then?

Comment: Great question, @Twisty.  That will help answer a bunch of remaining questions.  (e.g., does the Wi-Fi equipment in the laptop work?  Is the Layer 2 association, i.e. "connecting to the SSID" working?)  If it can't be done manually, then DHCP's failure is not a surprise.

Comment: Is the wireless adapter setup to connect without DHCP (static)? There have been a few occasions where I have forgotten to reset the adapter to DHCP and as a result the computer never got a proper address.

Comment: What is your router model number? (the one that you're using for WiFi). Also, your laptop model as well. Regarding VirtualBox, yes it's important, you should disable VirtualBox network adapters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 1):

There is many possible solutions:

1. completely disable or uninstal AV firewall, reinstall network drivers, and test - I see frequently problems with WiFi after AV firewal bug - if it help, then reinstall AV
2. test your network interface - connect to network, set static IP and ping gate
3. check services status - run services.msc, find:

   - `WLAN AutoConfig Service`
   - `dhcp client service`

   Try stop and start, these services should be set to start automaticity.
4. 'Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter' - go to devices manager, disable this network card and tray reconnect to WiFi
5. install newest drivers for `Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260`
6. check system event log, find errors and dhcp client logs

Answer (score 0):

It's a try.

Using a live-linux-distro to see if the hardware works properly.

Or manually resetting the TCP/IP protocol as follows:

1. Run **cmd.exe** as Administrator
2. Type, `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` (or use your preferred file path)
3. Restart your computer

Or using an easy-fix from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299357/how-to-reset-tcp-ip-by-using-the-netshell-utility)

You could try to use another [easy-fix](http://aka.ms/diag_networking10) too, if the first doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have 2 mac address that are the same they are both different:

```
AC-FD-CE-E6-BF-0E
AE-FD-CE-E6-BF-0E
```

To test if it is your router plug your computer directly into the router. Do an `ipconfig` and see if you get an IP address from the default gateway. If you still do not get an IP depending on your connection type, if it is PPPoE connect your computer directly into the wall and dial the connection manually from your network and sharing center. If your direct IP get the IP address assigned to your router and inset the static ip into your wireless lan adaptor.

If your using VDSL, ADSL1 or 2 or any other phone line connection you will need to replace your modem to eliminate if its the modem but before doing this I would plug a different computer into the router/modem to see if it replicates the issue of not receiving the ip address.

If non of this resolves your issue then you most likly have an issue at your node and i would contact your ISP and get them to send out a tech, hope this helps.