# Controlling/Understanding DHCP server (or not) on Hyper-V internal network on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, dhcp, hyper-v

I'd like to be able to have a reliable IP address for my host (which is Windows 10 and the machine running hyper-v) on the internal network hyper-V creates. By default, the host gets an IP (via what I originally thought was DHCP, but I now understand to be [APIPA/auto-IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958957.aspx)) on the internal network of the form 169.254.x.x with a 255.255.0.0 subnet mask.

I could just give it a static IP address in the adapter properties, but I've no idea what range of IPs are dynamically assigned, so I worry the static IP I pick could be dynamically assigned to a Hyper-V VM.

If I was on Windows Server, there'a a GUI and cmdlets to control DHCP server stuff, and I'm guessing I could apply those to the local DHCP server that is running on the host. But I'm not. Is there any way to create DHCP reservations for MAC ranges on the internal network on Windows 10? Or any way to know the range of IPs the internal adapter will use so that I can pick a static IP safely?

Comment: "I have no idea what range of IPs are dynamically assigned" - You should know this, you indicated the host is assigned an ip address within the 196.254.x.x subnet.  You will need to determine and provide the exact subnet configuration of the DHCP server to answer your question

Comment: Right - but I've no idea how I can get at this information. Hyper-V/Windows 10 is running a dhcp server, and I can tell it's offering IPs on the 169.254.x.x subnet just by looking at adapter properties in ipconfig. But how/where this dhcp server is configured is really the gist of my question.

Comment: You defined the ranage when you added the [DHCP role](http://techgenix.com/how-to-install-configure-windows-server-2008-dhcp-server/).  If you mean the Windows 10 VM is acting as the DHCP server, then you have to provide more details, because Windows 10 doesn't normally have that capability.

Comment: Windows 10 is on the machine running Hyper-V (not a VM). I'll edit to reflect.

Comment: I understand you are running a VM, and that VM is the DHCP, and I would assume its running Windows Server.  The host i understand is Windows 10.

Comment: Looking more carefully, the IP addresses being handed out are "APIPA", so there's likely no DHCP involved. But some algorithm is handing out IPs, I just would like to know how stable they are and what range are handed out.

Comment: @Ramhound; sorry if my question was confusing. The VM is not the DHCP. Rather, VMs are getting APIPA addresses and the host and VM can communicate via these APIPA addresses. I'll try to learn more about APIPA, update my question to be clearer, and report what I learn.

Comment: Your still asking about DHCP though.

Comment: @aggieNick02 If the machine (virtual or physical) is getting the 169.254.x.x range IP assigned to it, then this simply means that the NIC on that machine (physical or virtual) is trying to get an IP address from a DHCP server but it cannot a DHCP address and thereby it assigns the Automatic Private IP Address (APIPA) to that NIC since no DHCP and no static IP addresses are assigned. Assign the TCP/IP settings static settings to be sure there's a DHCP that's will assign IP addresses which it can talk with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand this better now. All the generated IP addresses for the virtual network (both host and VM) are APIPA/link-local, so there isn't actually a DHCP server running anywhere.

[It sounds like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4) the algorithm for generating these addresses actually checks to make sure that the address isn't in use elsewhere on the subnet, so I think I'm actually fine just using any static IP in the  169.254.0.1 to 169.254.255.254 block.