# How to RDC via local adapter instead of wireless network?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, ethernet, wired-networking

I have these two computers, both joined to my home wireless network. I frequently access either of them using RDC from the other with no problem. I have large video files to transfer via the RDC and the wireless network transfer when using Wi-Fi is very slow.

I connected the two computers together via their Ethernet ports—one directly plugged into the other—with a Cat 5 crossover Ethernet cable. With this connection they can both successfully `ping` each other and access shared folders between the via Windows Explorer when one or both is disconnected from the wireless network.

However, regardless of this disconnected wireless network status, RDC will not connect.

**It displays the common message:**

> Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:
>
> 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
>
> 2) The remote computer is turned off
>
> 3) The remote computer is not available on the network
>
> Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

I first fixed their LAN IP addresses and assigned `169.254.128.110` to one and  and `.112` last octet to the other, and made both use `255.255.0.0` for the subnet mask.

After that I tried connecting from one to the other on both computers with both computer names and IP addresses. I also tried disabling wireless adapter on both of them, but I cannot determine a configuration at this level that allows the connection from either of the computers.

This is something that I usually do when I want to connect to my laptop, I connect the laptop to one of these with the cable, then disable network adapter on the laptop, that it can be reachable just from cable and run RDC on the PC and done! But I don't know what is wrong between PCs.

What else should I check to find the problem or what else should I further troubleshoot?

---

### My Configuration

I have what we'll name `PC1`, `PC2` and `Laptop1` in a home network. They all happily connect each other via RDC when they can reach each other through WLAN.

When I disconnect them from wireless network and wire two of them up at a time using same crossover wire, `Laptop1` connects both `PC1` and `PC2` and vice versa. But `PC1` and `PC2` wont connect each other, however, they can ping each other.

There is no firewall appliance, no router, no gateway, same subnet mask and assigned static IPs from same range but different from wireless network IP range. `PC1` and `PC2` are running Win 7 x86 and the laptop is running Win 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Troubleshooting RDP Access

> **Note:** In this case to be thorough with testing, I suggest disabling both the Wi-Fi adapters beforehand. You may also want to test all these options thoroughly and be sure to only use what's needed to allow the access if you can pinpoint the specific settings so I'll give a "general" breakdown to assist.

1. **Assign a valid IP Address...** The `169.254.X.X` subnet range is an indicator that the NIC tried to get an IP address via DCHP but couldn't get one and thus it assigned an [Automatic Private IP Addressing (APIPA)](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/APIPA.html). This just means you should configure static IP addresses between the two machine's LAN port on the same subnet so perhaps `192.168.2.10` on one and then `192.168.2.11` on the other and just give them a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0` and leave both the default gateways blank—not confirm both can `ping` each other and get a response of success.
2. **Enabled Remote Desktop Access...** To ensure Remote Desktop access is enabled on the machines you wish to RDC into, you want to run this command from administrator elevated command prompt.

   - > ```
     > reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
     > ```
3. **Confirm if Windows Firewall is blocking...** To test to ensure the Windows Firewall is not blocking the TCP port 3389 traffic, you can disable the firewall on both Windows machines using an administrator elevated command prompt with the command listed below and the test to see if you can connect. If so, the culprit is the Windows Firewall.

   - **Disable Windows Firewall Command:** `advfirewall set allprofiles state off`
   - **Re-Enable Windows Firewall Command:** `advfirewall set allprofiles state on`
4. **Open Windows Firewall for RDC access...** If it is determined that the Windows Firewall is blocking the traffic, you can add a new Windows Firewall rule from an administrator elevated command prompt on both machines with the below syntax to tell it to accept **TCP** port **3389** connections from machines on the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet in the `domain`, `private` and `public` network profiles. I named the rule below `__Allow Inbound RDP` so if you go to `wf.msc` and then look in the **Inbound Rules**, you can see the settings this sets there.

   - > ```
     > netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="__Allow Inbound RDP" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=3389 remoteip=192.168.2.0/24 enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
     > ```

   Additionally, to go along with the above **#4** custom Windows Firewall rule, consider checking the default **Inbound** rule named **Remote Desktop (TCP-In)** rule from the same `wf.msc` and check the **Scope** tab and consider adding the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet range, and from the **Range** tab, consider checking all the `Profiles` there but play with the settings and test to see which options work for you that are the most restrictive if you can.

---

### Additional Issues

If you connect to the RDP session of a machine and get an error or quick pop up indicating **You cannot proceed because authentication is require**, then you can run the below command in an administrator elevated command prompt to change the [`SecurityLayer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-terminalservices-rdp-winstationextensions-securitylayer) setting in the registry. In some cases the pop up is quick and hard to see so it may be worth setting this if you get a quick pop up but cannot see the error detail and the connection is not established.

- > ```
  > reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" /v SecurityLayer /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
  > ```

---

### Security Considerations

It sounds like you only have these machines connected to a local crossover cable from LAN-to-LAN port so if that's the case and you do not allow TCP port 3389 to be directed from your WAN Internet connection of your router to either of these machines IP addresses on Wi-Fi or LAN, then you likely don't have much to worry about assuming you don't have these connected to a large network with lots of people that access it. So if you trust the devices connected to your local network via the Wi-Fi or Ethernet, then don't worry if you don't have this opened from the network.

If you do have these machines connected to a large network that many people access and there would be a concern with someone running brute force attacks internally to gain the RDC access guessing at the password, then there are a few things to consider.

1. Be sure the local accounts on the laptop that are allowed Remote Desktop access have super long and complex passwords such as "`Th1s 1s my r3mot3 m@ch1n3!!`" so as long as it around 14 characters or longer you can make it cryptic yet a phrase that's easy to remember as in the example I wrote there.

   - If there are any built-in account or other local account, be sure those are disabled or change the password on them to be super long and cryptic and if possible, disallow those accounts RDP access entirely.
2. You also want to be sure the local accounts are set to lock out after 3-5 authentication failures for the account that failed to authenticate. Read over the [Windows 7 – How to set up a Password and Account Lockout Policy](https://uwnthesis.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/windows-7-how-to-set-up-a-local-password-policy/) for more detail on some of this.
3. Lastly, it may be best also to only enable the Windows Firewall rule that allows this access from the machine(s) when you need to use the RDC access. This way the machine(s) is/are only vulnerable during the period you wish to use the protocol for access.

---

### Further Resources

- [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range/1106943#1106943)
- [Top 10: Windows Firewall Netsh Commands](http://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/top-10-windows-firewall-netsh-commands)
- [Firewall Rule Properties Page: Scope Tab](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771905(v=ws.11).aspx)
- [Understanding Firewall Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/getting-started-wfas-firewall-profiles-ipsec(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [SecurityLayer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-terminalservices-rdp-winstationextensions-securitylayer)

Answer (score 0):

If the computers can see each other but you are unable to connect via RDC, then you'll want to check the firewall settings on the destination machine; ensure that port **3389** is allowing traffic through in order for Remote Desktop to connect successfully.

Comment: Is that something that may differ when I use different interfaces? Because at the time I can connect when both are connected via WLAN.

Comment: Have you tried entering the destination machine's IP Address instead of the hostname?

Comment: Yes, I have, but no difference.

Comment: Compare the properties of the network profiles (wireless and wired) on one or both of the computers and identify what's different

Comment: If you mean IPv4 properties, then nothing. Everything is set to their defaults. First "Obtain IP Automatically" was selected, that I changed it to "Use Selected ..." on both machines. No difference if it's automatic or not.

Comment: Bear in mind that your wireless adapter and your wired adapter are separate devices; their MAC addresses are different and on Windows, you can't bind the same IP address to 2 different MAC addresses. Your wireless adapter and wired adapter will have different IP addresses even though they are on the same machine.

Comment: Sure, I tried different IPs from same and different ranges than the wireless network (which is 192.168.1.*).

Comment: I don't know where to start... "i wired them" How? Is there a switch, a router, or a hub involved? A crossover cable?  Next, I don't see any mention of a gateway, its kinda important.  Both devices need one, and only one. Next, Use the Ethernet interface or use the wireless interface, but don't turn them both on at the same time. Next, What does the routing table say?( use Route print)

Comment: It is possible that your wireless connection is set home network, while the wired connection is being identified as public and has different firewall rules.